# How do I get the Crystal Heart in Chapter 4?

Tags: celeste

In one area during the second part of Chapter 4, the Crystal Heart is positioned high above Madeline and apparently out of reach:

[image: Crystal Heart positioned high above Madeline]

The area contains a Mario-style block at the bottom, but I'm not sure how this relates to the puzzle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried holding <kbd>↓</kbd> on the D-pad in different places, assuming that the Mario reference was related to some sort of hidden "pipe", and it turns out I needed to **stand on top of the white Mario block and hold down**:

[image: Mario block]

The tricky part is that you need to hold <kbd>↓</kbd> for longer than you might expect, until Madeline "sinks in" and goes into the background. From there, you can use the background terrain (the light pink area) to reach the Crystal Heart.

Comment: The "Mario block" is a reference to the secret warp whistle in Super Mario Bros. 3 stage 1-3. There's a very similar white platform that Mario can press down on to fall "behind" the foreground objects and access a secret area. More detail about it [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/189128/95725).